# Can I call Salesforce to get mandatory fields removed from my organisation?

Tags: required-field, salesforce-support

We do not use a number of fields on opportunity, opportunity product, and service contract line items and would like to at the very least remove them from the page layouts.

But alas we can't. Our sales process and the way we charge for our products is different from how the opportunity products, products, and pricebooks work together on Salesforce. We've made all the custom fields and got them working how we want them, but we still can't remove things like Sales Price from the opportunity products layout.

Is there a way to get rid of it without having to speak to support? They just don't seem to help.

Comment: I'd be rather suprised (but im not sure) if they can do that. If may have been better to use a custom object if you do not want to use much of the standard functionality.

Comment: Good question...i too needed this for one of my client...

Comment: How do you sell things without a sale price?

Comment: Rental and installation fees, and commission.